# Python Beatifulsoup tag name and attribute conflict

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup elements have a `.text` attribute (a property version of the [`.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)).

BeautifulSoup also lets you access tags like attributes:

```
soup.firstparent.secondparent.dosomething #etc
```

Now, for unfortunate but immutable reasons, my task is to access a `<text>` element, which you'd access with:

```
soup.firstparent.text.dosomething 
#in this case, 'text' tag is child node of the 'firstparent' tag
```

This, however, conflicts with the `.text` property BeautifulSoup offers. The question is - how can I access a tag named `text`, and avoid conflicts with the BeautifulSoup property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute access is a convenience; you can still use `.find()` to search for a tag:

```
soup.firstparent.find('text').dosomething
```

The `.find('text')` call will search for the first `<text>` tag, not invoke the BeautifulSoup `.text` property.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <div><text>Hello world!</text></div>''')
>>> soup.div.text
u'Hello world!'
>>> soup.div.find('text')
<text>Hello world!</text>
```

Comment: Thank you, somehow, totally forgot 'bout this function. Used already, as you answered shorter.